# Connecting to Python Server via C# Client

Tags: c#, python, tcp, server, client

I/we've got a tiny problem here.
We are trying to connect to a server, written in python, with a client, written in C#, via TCP connection.

I'm capable of connecting to Port 80, but to none else. Is there any big mistake we are looking at?
Furthermore we tried running the server (python) on a usual PC as well as on a webspace.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpClient socket = new TcpClient();
        socket.Connect("<my ip here>", 8585);

        if(socket.Connected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("connected!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("connection failed!");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Server: [Click here](http://pastebin.com/eipn4urA)

Comment: There is port = 8686 in Python and 8585 here.

Comment: Oh, right, that happened 'cause we tried severeal ports actually.

Comment: So, it doesn't work when the ports are the same?

Comment: Correct, we can't establish a connection on any (random) port.

Comment: Are they running on the same host (localhost)? Or what is the value for `<my ip here>`?

Comment: No, we tried running them on 2 private PC's and tried running them on 1 PC and a python-able webspace. <my ip here> is just a placeholder for the webspaces ip.

Comment: Can you ping this webspace or maybe try it out locally? It is working locally for me, but says `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`in `conn.send(..)`.

Comment: Ye, i can ping the webspace and with this C# script even connect to Port 80 (HTTP) to it, so the script seems to work. And locally it works for us as well.

Comment: Then the webspace seems to be blocking port 8686. Can you make the python server bind to port 80?

Answer (score 0):

Can you also ping the webspace including port 8686 like  `http://localhost:8686`?

Maybe the webspace provider is blocking port 8686.

Try to bind the port of the python server to port 80.

**Update**:

When the webspace does not allow binding to port 80, then try to make it open port 8686 or change the provider:)

You can still try it on localhost.

Comment: Actually we thought about that, too. Unfortunately binding it to Port 80 throws and "Exception which caused another exception"

Comment: This is the output of the webspace when running the server bound to port 80? "Exception which caused another exception"

Comment: At the moment we are using www.pythonanywhere.com , since it's free and we are just testing small scripts like those. Do you have any other (free) alternative? :)

Comment: What's your configuration on pythonanywhere.com? How do you start the script?

Comment: using the live console?